# Failed to iterate 2D array converted from dict object

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to filter some data with dictionary like using a map or object,
and when thing is done, the item should be output as 2D array for easy importing back into spreadsheet.

But the following code returns error from failed reading `arr(1,1)` which it say something like `index is out of range`, why?

```
Sub DictToArr()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, arr As Variant
    dict.Add "item 1", Array("value 1", "value 2")
    dict.Add "item 2", Array("value 3", "value 4")
       
    arr = dict.Items
    Debug.Print arr(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Is there a way to directly assign this array format `arr(i)(j)` into a spreadsheet?, or directly convert `dict.items` into this array format `arr(i, j)` ?

Comment: `Debug.Print arr(1)(1)`

Comment: @braX why? so it isn't a normal 2D vba array?

Comment: is there a way to directly assign this array format ```arr(i)(j)```into spreadsheet?, or directly corvert ```dict.items``` into this array format ```arr(i,j)``` ?

Comment: Have you looked at it thru a Watch? https://i.stack.imgur.com/RshDg.png

Comment: @braX thanks, I’m new in VBA, and is so confused with the syntax. Knowing that 2D arrays could be presented in both ```array(i,j)``` and ```array(i)(j) ``` and can be 0 indexing but array values from sheet range always start from index 1,  all these things get my mind blown.

Comment: Try this: `Range("A1:B1") = dict("item 1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop thru each dictionary item and apply row by row like this.

I'm sure there are other ways.
You could convert it from an array of 1D arrays to a 2D array, but why add an intermediary step?

```
Sub DictToWorksheet()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict.Add "item 1", Array("value 1", "value 2", "extra test")
    dict.Add "item 2", Array("value 3", "value 4")
       
    Dim Row As Long : Row = 1
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
      ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1).Resize(1, UBound(dict(Key)) + 1) = dict(Key)
      Row = Row + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

And to be clear, this is not a 2D array as stated in your title. This is a keyed collection of 1D arrays. (Maybe that's why the output wasn't what you expected.)

I added an additional "extra test" to illustrate that the upper bound for each item can be different, and 2D arrays will not work like that.

---

Speed depends on the size of the Dictionary. If you are talking about a couple of dozen items/arrays, then row by row will probably be just fine speed-wise. However, if there are thousands of items, then it would be better to convert it to a 2D array to transfer to the spreadsheet all at once.

For the basics on creating a 2D array:

Note the hard coded values for the array. You will want to adjust those accordingly.

I think you are mostly interested in the loop part of the code anyway.

```
Function DictTo2DArray() As String()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict.Add "item 1", Array("value 1", "value 2") ' number of items here determines size of array
    dict.Add "item 2", Array("value 3", "value 4")
    dict.Add "item 3", Array("value 5", "value 6")
        
    Dim Result2D() As String
    ReDim Result2D(1 To dict.Count, 1 To UBound(dict("item 1")) + 1) ' match the name of the first key
    
    Dim Row As Long : Row = 0
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
      For Col = 0 To UBound(dict(Key))
        Result2D(Row + 1, Col + 1) = dict(Key)(Col) ' look familiar? Debug.Print arr(1)(1)
      Next
      Row = Row + 1
    Next
    
    DictTo2DArray = Result2D

End Function
```

You can probably make this better with a more dynamically allocated array, but with only sample data it's hard to know what way is going to work best for you. This is just meant to show you how the loop works.

Comment: won't it impact the performance if we apply values to the spreadsheet row by row? I mainly use google spreadsheet with apps-script and javascript before, so I am used to do things like load all data, process the data with code to get the fianl result, and put the results back into the sheet in one go, this will be like 1000 times faster than work things out row by row in apps-script. If VBA don't have this performance issue, maybe I should try your suggestion.

Comment: Well you can leave the question open for others to answer if you like. As I said, there are other ways, and maybe someone else will be able to come up with a solution without a loop. I wanted to at least show you that the dictionary is not a 2D array. It is unclear to me why you would need to set things up like this in the first place tho.

Comment: I mean, why is the data in a dictionary in the first place? If you are worried about speed, this seems like an extra step. Seems like the code that populates the dictionary could just as easily just populate the spreadsheet instead, if that is the goal.

Comment: I used the dict to get sum of a set of uniqe key values from the spreadsheet, for example I have this data: { {Key_1, 10}, {Key_2, 5}, {Key_3, -1} }, I run the values into dict with the dict key as keys and save the sum as items

Comment: then I want to set the result into an easy format that can directly apply back into the spread sheet, so I was seeking a way to turn the dict back into array format

Comment: I think no matter which way you do it, it's going to involve some sort of loop on the dictionary, even to get it into a 2D array format. I could be wrong. Then it just comes down to speed tests.

Comment: @Ping The above code **does not** "apply values to the spreadsheet row by row"!. It works only in memory and load `Result2D` array. The resulted array content can/should be dropped **at once** in the necessary sheet.

Comment: @FaneDuru there are 2 codes, the first one is row by row.

Comment: Ups... I looked only to the second one. It would probably be good to show him how the resulted array can be dropped on the range. And I also think it would be better to declare `Result2D() As String` and `ReDim` if after loading the dictionary (in base 1): `ReDim Result2D(1 To dict.count, 1 To UBound(dict("item 1")) + 1)`. And, of course, loading the array using `Result2D(Row + 1, Col + 1) = dict(Key)(Col)`...

Comment: yeah, @FaneDuru is right. I was just showing the basics involved as it was sample data. It looked like he knew how to handle the array.

Comment: @braX, you could avoid the use of Row variable, by using array rows indexes directly as keys, e.g.:  dict.Add 0, Array("value 1", "value 2")  , dict.Add 1, Array("value 3", "value 4"), ... and finally Result2D(Key, Col) = dict(Key)(Col)

Comment: I rather like using the `Row` variable, as it's more explicit for someone who is trying to learn from it, much in the same way I was explicit with `ActiveSheet` in the first code.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions and comment’s, the whole story is, I used to work with javascript. JS, 2DArray is accessed like by ```arr[0][0]```, that is why I thought ```arr(0)(0)``` is a presentation of 2DArray of VBA. Since dictionaries are considered as pairs or data as ```"Key", "Value"``` which share many features as what normal Object does in JS, I consider ```dict.items``` as similar methods as ```Object.values(obj)``` which returns an array of all Object values, in JS, if the value you put into the Object keys are arrays, the output of ```Object.values(obj)``` will be a 2DArray.

Comment: I don't program in javascript, but that seems messy to me. Glad to see you got things sorted.

Comment: ya, I was so confused that I spent 2 full days crashing into errors since I strted my VBA project lol, which what I am trying to do is so simple that I could have get it done already in like half an hour with javascript.